# Visual Studio Code don't find selenium

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv in python and then installed with all modules needed to my project.

requests
certifi
beatifulsoap4
...

If i run the program in the integrated terminal in visual studio code, it works fine. 
But If use de command "Run Code" - *CTRL+Alt+N* - in visual studio code I get the follow error

```
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I already changed the python path to point to my virtualenv but problem persist.

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python3"
}
```

If i change my code to not use selenium, then the "Run Code" command works fine (eveen with others imports)

Comment: There isn't a `Run Code` commend in VS Code or the Python extension. Do you have another extension installed for running code?

Comment: 'Crtl + Alt + N'

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+N (at least on Windows) is not a default keybinding on Windows, so I suspect you have an extension installed that isn't the Python extension for VS Code which you are using to run code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, Selenium was installed but Visual Studio was not able to import it.
In Laymen's term:

> The thing is Selenium is installed but VS Code can't access it, and
> you need link both them.

That's how I solved it.

- Uninstall Selenium using `pip uninstall selenium`
- Then create a New Folder on your preferred location, (Like Desktop,
  or D drive, etc.)
- Open that folder in Visual Studio Code.
- Now go to the Terminal of VS Code and create a Virtual Environment
  (Google python Virtual Environment if you don't know how to create
  one)
- Then, install selenium in that virtual Environment using `pip install selenium`
- You will see some files are included in your folder after    pip
  install selenium (`pipfile` and `pipfile.lok`)
- Lastly, install pyLint to your virtual environment using  `pipenv install pylint --dev`

> If you still get an error, open your command-line and install selenium
> on your PC. Previously we installed it only in our virtual
> environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode with anaconda, re-installing selenium package thru anaconda prompt instead of cmd/vscode terminal might help.

I had installed bs4 & selenium thru cmd, but it was not able to import selenium in vscode. (while importing bs4 was fine)
I was using vscode with anaconda, so I tried to re-install selenium thru anaconda prompt.
After that, I was finally able to import selenium in vscode.

I don't have much knowledge about computer and softwares, so I don't know why this happened but anyways I resolved the problem using anaconda prompt.

hope it would be helpful for you  :)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem..what worked for me is instead of running the python file in VScode I tried some other interpreter and it worked....but before that you need to check whether selenium is actually present or not in your local machine..you can do this in using terminal(on Mac)
open terminal.
type python3
type import selenium

if this runs without any kind of error then you are good to go

Comment: A workaround is not a solution, consider to check the already accepted answare.